# QTableWidget change selection mode

Tags: c++, qt, selection, qtablewidget

When clicking on `QTableWidget` cell, it selects only the cell. How to configure tablewidget, so that when click on a cell , the whole row will be selected which contains the cell?

It can be done using signal,slots. I'm curious is there standard way doing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use `setSelectionBehavior`

```
QTableView * tmp = new QTableView();
tmp->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#SelectionBehavior-enum

Comment: small spelling mistake on your answer, setSelectionBehaviour should change to setSelectionBehavior